# $\|fg\|_{A (\mathbb T)} \leq C \|f\|_{L^{2}} \|g\|_{A (\mathbb T)}$?

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb T)$ and define the Fourier coefficient of $f$ : $\hat{f}(n)=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int _{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t) e^{-int} dt; (n\in \mathbb Z)$.Consider the space,
 $$A(\mathbb T):= \{f\in L^{1}(\mathbb T): \hat{f}\in \ell^{1}(\mathbb Z), \  \text {that is,} \  \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} |\hat{f}(n)| < \infty \}.$$
$A(\mathbb T)$ is normed by the $L^{1}-$ norm on $\mathbb Z$:
$$||f||_{A(\mathbb T)}= \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} |\hat{f}(n)| < \infty; \ \text {for} \ f\in A(\mathbb T). $$
We also note that $A(\mathbb T)$ is a Banach algebra under pointwise addition and multiplication.

> **My Question**: Can we expect $\|fg\|_{A (\mathbb T)} \leq C \|f\|_{L^{2}} \|g\|_{A (\mathbb T)},$ ( where $C$ is some constant) for $f,g \in A(\mathbb T)$? If yes, how to prove it?

[We recall, $\|f\|^{2}_{L^{2}}= \int_{0}^{2\pi}|f(t)|^{2} dt= \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z}|\hat{f}(n)|^{2}$]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that
$$
\left\|\,f\vphantom{\hat{f}}\,\right\|_{A(\mathbb{T})}=\left\|\,\hat{f}\,\right\|_{\ell^1}
$$
Suppose $g(x)=1$. Then $\hat{g}(n)=[n=0]$, and therefore, $\|g\|_{A(\mathbb{T})}=1$. Then, your question asks if
$$
\left\|\,f\,\right\|_{A(\mathbb{T})}
\le C\left\|\,f\,\right\|_{L^2}
$$
which is impossible. For counterexample, we can look at
$$
\widehat{f_n}(k)=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}
\frac1{|k|}&\text{if }1\le|k|\le n\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.
$$
where $\|f_n\|_{A(\mathbb{T})}=2H_n$, yet $\|f_n\|_{L^2}\le\frac{\pi^2}3$, where $H_n$ is a [Harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

Comment: @Inquisitive: I have added that to the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot: just for curiosity: Can we expect this for $A(\mathbb R)$? ($A(\mathbb R)=\{f\in L^{\infty}: \hat{f}\in L^{1}(\mathbb R)\}$ (the algebra of Fourier transforms))

Comment: I mean: $\|fg\|_{A(\mathbb R)} \leq \|f\|_{L^{2}(\mathbb R)} \|g\|_{A(\mathbb R)}$? ($\|g\|_{A(\mathbb R)}:=\|\hat{g}\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb R)}$)

Comment: Let $g_k(x)=e^{-kx^2}$ and $f_k(x)=k^{1/2}e^{-kx^2}$. Scaling properties say that
$$\|g_k\|_{A(\mathbb{R})} =\|g_1\|_{A(\mathbb{R})}$$ and $$\|f_k\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})} =\|f_1\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}$$ yet $$\|f_kg_k\|_{A(\mathbb{R})}=k^{1/2}\|f_1g_1\|_{A(\mathbb{R})}$$